# HTML tag for Short Text

Tags: html

I need to display the following text on an HTML5 page:

```
John Smith
Web Designer
Member since 2018
```

My idea is to have something like:

```
<div class="user">
  <span>John Smith</span>
  <span>Web Designer</span>
  <span>Member since 2018</span>
</div>
```

And then use:

```
div.user span { display: block; }
```

Or should I wrap each text line in a P tag?

Usually I see P tags as for long text ...

For short text I tend to use:
- A (if it is a link); 
- SPAN (if it is no link);
- H (if it is a title).

My main doubt is what tab to use when it is a short text (2 to 4 words)?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you just want to display these words you can use `<br>` at the end of each line and wrap them all in a `<div>` but by using `<span>` you can then set classes and ids to each line to play around with styling etc.

Comment: http://microformats.org/wiki/microformats2#h-card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the HTML <br> tag, which seems to be the most simple way of achieving this without CSS.

```
<div class="user">
  John Smith<br>
  Web Designer<br>
  Member since 2018
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `div` for them if you want to show every item in a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a school-book case for XSLT.

Assuming that you have an XML file like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<div class="user">
  <span>John Smith</span>
  <span>Web Designer</span>
  <span>Member since 2018</span>
</div>
```

you can transform this with XSLT-1.0 or above to put a `<BR />` tag after each entry:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/div[@class='user']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="span"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span">
      <xsl:value-of select="." /><br />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, to put each entry inside a `<p>` tag, replace the second template with

```
<xsl:template match="span">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT you are flexible to create both outputs with a minimum of changes to the XSLT file and **no changes at all** to the input XML file.